# Lexical.js CLEAR_EDITOR_COMMAND won't dispatch

Tags: reactjs, lexicaljs

I've written simple plugin so i can push text from lexical to server:

```
const SubmitPlugin = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();

  const onEnter = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      const { ctrlKey, metaKey } = event;

      if (ctrlKey || metaKey) {
        event.preventDefault();

        onSubmit(
          dompyrify.sanitize($generateHtmlFromNodes(editor), {
            ALLOWED_ATTR: ['style'],
          }),
        );

        editor.dispatchCommand(CLEAR_EDITOR_COMMAND, undefined);
      }

      return true;
    },
    [editor],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    return mergeRegister(
      editor.registerCommand(KEY_ENTER_COMMAND, onEnter, COMMAND_PRIORITY_HIGH),
    );
  }, [editor, onEnter]);

  return null;
};
```

When i press Ctrl or CMD + Enter it calls onSubmit function. Everything works fine except for `editor.dispatchCommand(CLEAR_EDITOR_COMMAND, undefined);` part. It doesn't do anything. All i need is to clear editor

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that `CLEAR_EDITOR_COMMAND` is separated into plugin:

```
import { ClearEditorPlugin } from '@lexical/react/LexicalClearEditorPlugin';
```

and

```
return (
    <LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
      <RichTextPlugin
        contentEditable={<ContentEditable />}
        placeholder={<div className="placeholder">Reply...</div>}
      />
      <ClearEditorPlugin />

      <SubmitPlugin onSubmit={onSubmit} />
    </LexicalComposer>
  );
```

Now it works just fine